# Is there any short way to load data to the properties of a class, for each column name matching the properties of the class?

Tags: php, oop, class, properties, iterator

I want to load data to an instance of an object using its constructor and I write

```
$this->property=$row["colname"]
```

each time for each property.

the mysql_fetch_object function fetches the data as an object but I am not sure if the instance of an object can be assigned to some object from inside. othwerwise I would use

```
__construct($object) { $this=$object; } //doesn't give any syntax error
```

Maybe I should look into iteration of properties and use

```
foreach($object as $key => $value) $value=$object[$key];
```

or can I assign like

```
$this=$object;
```

within the constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign anything to `$this`, or you'll get an error.

I would do something like this:

```
class SomeObject 
{
    function __construct($base = null)
    {
        if ($base != null)
        {
            $this->load($base);
        }

        // continue construction as you normally would
    }

    function load($object)
    {
        foreach ($object as $key => $value)
        {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you have the option of load the array into the object at construction time, or after construction via `load()`.

---

#### Usage example:

```
$rows = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Foo');

// create an empty SomeObject instance
$obj = new SomeObject();
var_dump($obj);

// load $rows into the object
$obj->load($rows);
var_dump($obj);

// create an instance of SomeObject based on $rows
$rows2 = array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Bar');

$obj2 = new SomeObject($rows2);
var_dump($obj2);
```

#### Demo: http://codepad.org/uV7bOrfL

Comment: because if I can assign $this to the parameter of the constructor, I will use that.

Comment: can you explain what that "$base=null" does?

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan It's just the default argument for `$base`, so if you want to create the object without the base, it can do that.

Comment: yes, like the php documentation says, that would work, I was sure of that. I am wondering about assignment __construct($object) { $this=$object; }

Comment: As I said, you can't assign `$this` to anything

Comment: Can you give reference to any documentation page for that? because I am unable to find some page which says $this is not assignable.

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan I can't find the doc page on it, but here is a demo: http://codepad.org/blqwOBQ1